# Perl matching multiple capitalized words

Tags: regex, perl

I'm doing a perl program (script?) that reads through a text file and identifies all names and categorizes them as either person, location, organization, or miscellaneous.  I'm having trouble with things like New York or Pacific First Financial Corp. where there are multiple capitalized words in a row.  I've been using:

```
/([A-Z][a-z]+)+/
```

to capture as many capitalized words in a row as there are on a given line.  From what I understand the + will match 1 or more instances of such pattern, but it's only matching one (i.e. New in New York).  For New York, I can just repeate the [A-Z][a-z]+ twice but it doesn't find patterns with more than 2 capitalized words in a row.  What am I doing wrong?

PS Sorry if my use of vocabulary is off I'm always so bad with that.

Comment: For one, you need to allow for space and the possible next set of words and two use `*` meaning zero or more times instead of `+`.. `([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)`

Comment: What does the ?: mean?

Comment: It is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing the spacing between words.

The following matches whitespace before each word, except the first, so covers the cases you've described:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    while (/(?=\w)((?:\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)+)/g) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
I'm doing a perl program (script?) that reads through a text file and identifies all names and categorizes them as either person, location, organization, or miscellaneous. I'm having trouble with things like New York or Pacific First Financial Corp. where there are multiple capitalized words in a row. I've been using:

to capture as many capitalized words in a row as there are on a given line. From what I understand the + will match 1 or more instances of such pattern, but it's only matching one (i.e. New in New York). For New York, I can just repeate the [A-Z][a-z]+ twice but it doesn't find patterns with more than 2 capitalized words in a row. What am I doing wrong?

PS Sorry if my use of vocabulary is off I'm always so bad with that.
```

Outputs:

```
New York
Pacific First Financial Corp
From
New
New York
For New York
What
Sorry
```

Comment: Could do with an explanation of the changes to the RE

Comment: I think `/[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*/` is generally more understandable

Comment: @PeterR Agreed, that is simpler.  However, I arbitrarily decided that I wanted NewYork to pass as a capitalized word as well.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't noticed that functionality. To extend the simpler regex above to do that just flip a + to a * `/[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)*/`

I'm wondering what the relative performance of these two approaches is

Comment: Looks like the lookahead is slower by about a factor of 5

Comment: Got a factor of 7 now with some optimisation

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect a regex to be faster without a lookahead due to not having to follow two branches.  However, that's definitely a premature optimization, so clarity should be the primary motivation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a CPAN module called [Lingua::EN::NamedEntity](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::NamedEntity) which seems to do what you want. Might be worth taking a quick look at it.

Answer (score 1):

### The How

The pattern you provide, `/([A-Z][a-z]+)+/`, in your question matches one of more capitalised words given consecutively, like this

```
This
ThisAndThat
```

but it won't match this

```
Not This
```

It actually matches each of these individually

```
Not
This
```

So lets modify the regex to `/(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)(?:\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)*/`. Now that is a bit of a mouthful so lets break it down a bit at a time

```
(?: ... )      Groups like this don't capture which is more efficient
[A-Z][a-z]+    Matches a capitalised word
\s*[A-Z][a-z]+ Matches a subsequent capitalised word, optionally starting with
               whitespace
```

### The What - TL;DR

Put this all together and we now have a regex that matches a capitalised word, then any subsequent ones with or without whitespace seperation. So it matches

```
This
ThisAndThat
Not This
```

We can now abstract this regex a bit to avoid repetition and use it in code as so

```
my $CAPS_WORD = qr/[A-Z][a-z]+/;
my $FULL_RE   = qr/(?:$CAPS_WORD)(?:\s*$CAPS_WORD)*/;

$string =~ /$FULL_RE/;
say $&;
```

### The Why

This answer gives an alternative to the already great one given by @Miller, both will work fine but this solution is quite a bit faster since it doesn't use a lookahead. [This](http://uploads.peter-r.co.uk/misc/bench-simple.pl) is faster than [this](http://uploads.peter-r.co.uk/misc/bench-lookahead.pl) by a factor of 7

```
$ time ./bench-simple.pl
Running 100000 runs
800000 matches

real    0m2.869s
user    0m2.860s
sys     0m0.008s

$ time ./bench-lookahead.pl
Running 100000 runs
800000 matches

real    0m19.845s
user    0m19.831s
sys     0m0.012s
```